# Can I start the another cluster from current notebook in Databricks?

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I have notebook1 assigned to cluster1 and notebook2 assigned to cluster2.
I want to trigger notebook2 from notebook1 but notebook2 should use only cluster2 for execution.
Currently its getting triggered using Cluster1.
Please let me know for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot start another cluster from current notebook.

This is excepted behaviour, when you trigger notebook2 from notebook it will use cluster1 and not cluster2.

**Reason:** When you run any command from notebook1, always runs on the attached cluster.

Notebooks cannot be statically assigned to a cluster; that's actually runtime state only. If you want to run some code on a different cluster (in this case, the code is a notebook), then you have to do it by having your first notebook submit a separate job, rather than using `dbutils.notebook.run` or `%run`.

[image]

**Notebook Job Details:**

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.